# Auto mount ntfs drive with permissions of rwx for each user in Ubuntu

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I have a drive (logical) with `ntfs` system. I want it be mounted automatically whenever Ubuntu starts. And since `ntfs` doesn't support Linux files' permissions (`rwx`) I want it to be mounted with max permissions, meaning each user in Ubuntu can run, read and execute every file in that `ntfs` drive.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto mounting NTFS can be tricky. I found [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G) very helpful.

Good luck!